# Where can I add a mage into my party after the completion of the main storyline?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I had Solas in my party for the whole game, however he is gone after the main quest line is completed and it looks there is no change to enter quest for get Vivienne or Dorian Pavus (in fact it looks it is not possible even before the *What Pride Had Wrought* quest). I would like to finish some of the side quests and the only one I can get those is either without a mage in the group or from an old save (and I don't like either of these options).

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There are only 3 mages companions: Solas, Vivienne, and Dorian.
- Solas will leave after you completed the main storyline.
- Almost all quests related to companions will become unavailable after you completed the main storyline.

Hence, if you did not recruit all of the companions before the last quest, you will not be able to do so later on.
For your case, unfortunately, there are no other options to get a mage anymore unless you replay it from an old save.